# JOGL | Как связать класс для создания окна с классом интерфейса jogl?

Tags: java, canvas, jogl

Пробовал разобраться в jogl и наговнокодил несколько небольших проектов по урокам. Решил написать небольшой движок и все наработки уместить уже в новый проект. Там три класса:

- Main (просто вызывает мейн и запускает Game)
- Game - класс с интерфейсом GLEventListener.
- Display - класс для создания и управления окном, который вызывается из конструктора Game.

Как правильно связать нужные компоненты из Display в Game(и какие)? Видимо этот Canvas, созданный в Display нужно как-то передать в Game для обработки(я так понял, на канвасе опенджиЕл рисует всю графику).

Если всё это уместить в один класс, то эта магия как-то работает))

класс Display:

```
package by.lagx.display;


import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

import by.lagx.io.Input;

public class Display {
    private static boolean created = false;
    private static JFrame window;
    private static GLCanvas content;
    static GLCapabilities capabilities;

    public Display(final int x, final int y, final String title){
         final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get( GLProfile.GL2 );

        if(created)
            return;

        capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
        window = new JFrame(title);
        content = new GLCanvas(capabilities);

        Dimension size = new Dimension(x, y);
        content.setPreferredSize(size);

        window.setResizable(false);
        window.getContentPane().add(content);                     
        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

        final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(content,300,true);
        animator.start();
        created = true;
    }

    public static void destroy(){
        if(!created)
            return;

        window.dispose();
    }

    public static void setTitle(String title){//debug
        window.setTitle(title);
    }

    public static void addInputListener(Input inputListener){//для ввода
        window.add(inputListener);
    }

}
```

класс Game:

```
package by.lagx.game;

import by.lagx.display.Display;

import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;

public class Game implements GLEventListener{
    private GLU glu;

    public Game(){

    Display window = new Display(500, 400, "Привет))");
     glu = new GLU();
    }


    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {//здесь уже весь рендер
        final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
         gl.glClear( GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
            gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The View
            gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f,-5.0f);

            gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);

                gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  
                gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f);  
                gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f,  -1.0f,  0.0f); 
                gl.glVertex3f(1.0f,  -1.0f, -0.0f);  
            gl.glEnd();
            gl.glFlush();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {//наверное для расчетов 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {//видимо это для глобальных настроек
        final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);

    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {//хз что это, но, видимо, что-то связанно с дисплеем и его настройками 
          GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

            if( height <= 0 )
               height = 1;

            final float h = ( float ) width / ( float ) height;
            gl.glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
            gl.glMatrixMode( GL2.GL_PROJECTION );
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            glu.gluPerspective( 45.0f, h, 1.0, 20.0 );
            gl.glMatrixMode( GL2.GL_MODELVIEW );
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

    }


}
```

ну и класс Main:

```
 package by.lagx.main;

import by.lagx.game.Game;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ближе к утру, после многочисленных попыток заметил строку:

```
content.addGLEventListener( obj);
```

именно оно связывает полотно и реализацию интерфейса GLEventListener.
 Далее с помощью конструктора и двух заклинаний:

```
Game game = new Game();
Display window = new Display(900, 500, "Hi", game);
```

освободил магию неведомой силы))